# How can I update the solrconfig.xml in Cloudera Search?

Tags: solr, cloudera, solrcloud

I know the steps to create a new collection in Cloudera Search, but what I need is to update a current collection's solrconfig.xml file.

Any ideas on how to do that? I'm using the solrctl command

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
zkString="your-server-domain-or-ip:2181"

sh /opt/solr/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost "$zkString" -cmd upconfig -confname the-name-of-your-configuration -confdir /path/to/solrconfig/
```

Answer (score 0):

you should update your solrconfig and then reload collection configuration with the following command:

```
solrctl collection --reload <collection-name>
```